# Finding partially feasible solution in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

Consider the snippet:

```
# Original code was taken from https://benalexkeen.com/linear-programming-with-python-and-pulp-part-1/

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


# Constraints:
## 3x0 + 2x1 <= 5
## 4x0 - x1 <= 3
constraints = ["(5 - 3*x)/2.0", "- (3 - 4*x)/1.0"]

x = np.linspace(-10.5, 10.5, 2000)
### Taking x1 at RHS
### 3x0 + 2x1 <= 5
y1 = eval(constraints[0])
### 4x0 - x1 <=  3
y2 = eval(constraints[1])

# Make plot
plt.plot(x, y1, 'blue', label=r'$'+constraints[0]+'$')
plt.plot(x, y2, 'red', label=r'$'+constraints[1]+'$')
plt.xlim((-10, 10))
plt.ylim((-10, 10))
plt.xlabel(r'$x$')
plt.ylabel(r'$y$')

y3 = np.minimum(y1, y2) # Constraints of `<=` type

print (y3)
    
plt.plot(x, y3, 'green', label=r''+'overlap'+'')
#plt.fill_between(x, y1, y2, color='grey', alpha=0.5)
#plt.fill_between(x, y1, y3, color='pink', alpha=.5)
#plt.fill_between(x, y2, y3, color='yellow', alpha=.5)
plt.fill_between(x, y3, np.maximum(y1,y2), color='gray', alpha=.5)
#plt.fill_between(x, y2, y1, color='gray', alpha=.5)
#plt.fill_between(x, y1<=1, np.minimum(y1,y3), color='gray', alpha=.5)
#plt.fill_between(x, y3, y1, color='grey', alpha=0.5)
plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.05, 1), loc=2, borderaxespad=0.)
```

What I am able to get is the common feasible solution and the non-feasible solution of the inequalities, such as:
[image]

What I actually wanted is to shade the **partially feasible** solutions individually (the upper and the lower triangles in the figure). Say, only the top triangle is shaded, rest is kept as is.

I tried multiple combinations (as can be seen from the code snippet), but could not achieve this. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare some upper and lower curves. Horizontal boundaries are good enough. Here `y=-500` and `y=500` are set up. A large number, i.e. 500 is needed.

```
y_ge_m500 = (x*0) - 500  #for lower-y bound
y_le_p500 = (x*0) + 500  #for upper-y bound
```

Then use

```
plt.fill_between(x, y_ge_m500, np.minimum(y1, y2), color='yellow', alpha=.5)  #get lower ^
plt.fill_between(x, y_le_p500, np.maximum(y1, y2), color='pink', alpha=.5)    #get Upper V
```

And you will get a plot similar to this:

[image: output_plot]